# Files in volume are deleted when using docker-compose up

Tags: docker-compose, vapor

I have a Docker Compose setup with a web app in vapor and a database container. The web app container has a volume mounted to store user-uploaded files, like images. I noticed that when I rebuild the app container with docker-compose build and then start the containers with docker-compose up, the files in the volume are deleted. However, the items stored in the database are not deleted. How can I prevent the files in the volume from being deleted when I rebuild and start the containers (like when I'm pulling from github and restart my web-app ?

The pictures are stored inside a folder like that : itemPicture/

Here the code of docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  db_data:

x-shared_environment: &shared_environment
  LOG_LEVEL: ${LOG_LEVEL:-debug}
  DATABASE_HOST: db
  DATABASE_NAME: vapor_database
  DATABASE_USERNAME: vapor_username
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: vapor_password

services:
  app:
    image: leportantvaporapp:latest
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      <<: *shared_environment
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
#    user: '0' # uncomment to run as root for testing purposes even though Dockerfile defines 'vapor' user.
    command: ["serve", "--env", "production", "--hostname", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
  migrate:
    image: leportantvaporapp:latest
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      <<: *shared_environment
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: ["migrate", "--yes"]
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
  revert:
    image: leportantvaporapp:latest
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      <<: *shared_environment
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: ["migrate", "--revert", "--yes"]
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_USER: vapor_username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: vapor_password
      POSTGRES_DB: vapor_database
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

Comment: I don't see any other volume than `db_data` ... So it seems your uploads are stored with the container. Thus whenever you create a new container they are lost